# QGIS renders outlines where none should be

Tags: qgis, features, style, rendering

QGIS always renders the borders of a feature polygon. How can I disable this?

Even if I set Border style to "No Pen" and the colour is exactly the same for different categories there is a small grey border between adjoining features.

Unfortunately this border is even rendered when using the map composer:[image: qgis renders ghost borders]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround you may choose "Solid Line" option for borders, set the same colour to borders  and fill of the polygon and set border width to 0.0 .

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you're dealing with more than one colour-filters, setting the rendering order can also remove borders. Repeat the same steps as outlined by @SS_Rebelious (you do not have to change the border width) and click the **Rendering order...** button. Then set which filters has higher priority.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot you made my day. However this process is really cumbersome especially if you want to try different graduated combinations before picking the good one. IMHO "no pen" should behave more strictly speaking and add no border or gap of any kind. This answer is a nice quickfix, but this should be reported as a bug to the Qgis team. What do you think?

Comment: @MarHoff - Ha! Most welcome :). I understand what you mean (and feel free to report it) but I'm not exactly sure if it is a bug or if it's just in the way it was coded. I certainly agree that "no pen" should mean no borders but would be interesting to see what the devs think of this.