# Removing visual polygon borders in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, color, borders

I have a GML layer representing a hexagonal grid that I would like to include in some maps. In QGIS 2.14.2 I applied a graduated style and completely removed the polygon border:

[image]

However, in the map canvas the borders are still being portrayed:

[image]

Zooming in one can see the border around each polygon, it is thin, but it is still there:

[image]

Suspecting this was an issue with the map canvas itself, I tried to produce some maps with the Print Composer. Even in vector format, the polygon borders are portrayed. Please check these files:

- [PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20087409/Images/QGisHexagons/MapTest.pdf)
- [SVG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20087409/Images/QGisHexagons/MapTest.svg)

Is there any way to force QGIS to remove these borders?

Comment: If the user is selecting "no Pen" for the border, but the border still gets rendered, should not this be reported as a bug?

Comment: It is a long standing issue and is tracked in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/12023

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [`choropleth-gen`](https://github.com/ldesousa/choropleth-gen)

Tired of creating choropleths by hand for QGis I decided to create a little code package for the purpose. It has the suggestive name [`choropleth-gen`](https://github.com/ldesousa/choropleth-gen) and can be installed from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=choropleth-gen), issuing a command like:

`pip install choropleth-gen`

The package installs two scripts in the system: `gen_greyscale_choropleth` and
`gen_spectral_choropleth`. Both these scripts take the same arguments, 
identified with specific flags:

- `-b` - bottom value in the choropleth.
- `-t` - top value in the choropleth.
- `-c` - number of colour classes to generate.
- `-o` - path to the resulting SLD file.

Example:

`gen_spectral_choropleth -b 10 -t 50 -c 20 -o style.sld`

Comment: Luis, just wanted to thank you for your script. Used it today, and it was very helpful!

Comment: While nice, this really has nothing to do with the question about QGIS and really should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

The only way to that is to set the border color same as the fill color, then the border will disappear. You can keep setting the border line width is zero. Use 'Pick Color' to select exactly the same color from fill color.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Use Pick color to make the border color same as the filled color by selecting the filled color

[image]

The legend will look like this

[image]

And the final output is like this.

[image]

Comment: Like that I get a red border around each polygon. Which QGis version are you using?

Comment: You need to select the same color for each filled color. For example red fill -> red border, Blue filled -> blue border, and so on. That is why you need to use Pick color tool under the border color to pick the same filled color.

Comment: I spent the last 20 minutes modifying each and every class style and [the result is exactly the same](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20087409/Images/QGisHexagons/QGisStyles.png).

Comment: I updated the answer for more information.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - Try playing with the **rendering order** from the _Advanced_ button as described in this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112930/qgis-renders-outlines-where-none-should-be/113831#113831).

Comment: I do not have a *Rendering Order* option under the *Advanced* button.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - It could also be called _Symbol levels_.

Comment: The reason it hasn't worked for you is because you still have your border style set to "No Pen", so any changes you've done won't show. Change it to "Solid Line" and you should see the difference

Answer (score 5):

A way of doing this a little faster than @ahmadhanb (if you work with a color ramp for coloring) is to use the assistant by clicking on the symbol on the right and selecting "assistant" [image]

**In the "source" field you can insert the expression `@symbol_color` to receive the color that is used for the symbol's filling.**

---

If you need other coloring schemes, you can insert this or other rules:

```
CASE
WHEN "FieldNameYouUseForColoring"<200 THEN 0
WHEN "FieldNameYouUseForColoring"<400 THEN 1
WHEN "FieldNameYouUseForColoring"<600 THEN 2
END
```

Next, restrict the range to (0,2) and select the color ramp you would like to select.

Comment: You can use `@symbol_color` as expression, that will use the main color of the symbol. That way you do not need additional rules.