# Is there a way to hide range categories using Python code on a vector layer?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a routine to create a layer with 6 categories (see 1st graph) based on the values of the attributes. Is there a way I can hide the categories (see the 2nd graph) using Python code?
 [image]

```
def mapRange(layerName, fieldName):

    #https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31789/setting-color-of-feature-depending-on-attributes-with-pyqgis
    layerCat = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]

    values = (
    ('0.0-0.2', 0.0, 0.2, 'red'),
    ('0.2-0.4', 0.2, 0.4, 'orange'),
    ('0.4-0.6', 0.4, 0.6, 'yellow'),
    ('0.6-0.8', 0.6, 0.8, 'green'),
    ('0.8-1.0', 0.8, 1.0, 'blue'),
    ('Dry', -9999, -0.001, 'gray'))

    # create a category for each item in values
    ranges = []
    for label, lower, upper, color in values:
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layerCat.geometryType())
        symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
        #https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200094/how-to-define-border-colour-for-rule-based-style-using-pyqgis/220662
        layer_style = {}
        layer_style['color'] = color
        layer_style['color_border'] = color
        symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)
        if symbol_layer is not None:
            symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)

        rng = QgsRendererRange(lower, upper, symbol, label)
        ranges.append(rng)

    #create the renderer and assign it to a layer
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(fieldName, ranges)
    layerCat.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Comment: So you want to programmatically collapse the legend in the table of contents?

Comment: Yes. I have many of these layers created in each simulation run, and just want to open the legend of the layer of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal example of how to access layer tree objects such as QgsLayerTreeLayer or QgsLayerTreeGroup. These inherit the method setExpanded() from the QgsLayerTreeNode base class. So you can do the following:

```
layer_name = 'Name_of_your_layer'
p = QgsProject().instance()
r = p.layerTreeRoot()
c = r.children()
ll = [l for l in c if l.name() == layer_name][0]
ll.setExpanded(False) #Pass boolean value (True or False) to expand or collapse legend nodes
```

You can also use the isExpanded() method to check if layer tree items are already expanded or not. In this way, you could collapse all items like:

```
for l in c:
    if l.isExpanded():
        l.setExpanded(False)
```

And expand all:

```
for l in c:
    if not l.isExpanded():
        l.setExpanded(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Ben. Your answer really helps. I modified your code a little because the layers of interest are under a group.

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeLayer, QgsLayerTreeGroup
group_name = "simResultsGroup"
layer_name = "simResults"
p = QgsProject().instance()
r = p.layerTreeRoot()
c = r.children()

for l in c:
    if l.name() == group_name:
        for aLayer in l.findLayers():
            if aLayer.isExpanded():
                aLayer.setExpanded(False)
```