# Removing black lines in between shapes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, color, borders

In QGIS 3.22.7 I have a large dataset consisting of small square geometries (for reproducibility, a sample of this data [can be downloaded from here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bm5Yl9zqNVC58IuhYEgu3X9lDUXPXe7X?usp=sharing); the total file size is 9 KB for all of them).

When working with the larger dataset, I cannot zoom out far because the black lines hide the symbology. I have opened the symbology tab for the data and have selected the "graduated" option, as shown below:

[image]

This does not fix the black border lines between the shapefiles, however.

How can I set the borders to be the same color as the graduated color within each square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Stroke color to *Transparent* after selecting all the symbols (<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) in the Symbology tab.

[image: example1]

Click <kbd>Ok</kbd> > <kbd>Apply</kbd> > <kbd>Ok</kbd>, and get the output

[image: result1]

However, you may notice tiny white stripes somewhere in between polygons. To avoid that, use the [`@symbol_color`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) function instead of the *Transparent* color (via *Data Defines override (expression)*)

[image: example2]

then the symbology will look different

[image: result2]

---

**References:**

- [Removing polygon borders in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194277/removing-polygon-borders-in-qgis)

Comment: Thank so much! This is exactly what I was needing.