# How to remove QGIS polygon boundaries when using graduated style?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2.18

When I use a graduated style and I set the outline of the polygons to transparent I can still see the border. If I set the width to "Hairline" and/or the style to "No pen" I can still see them.

I have found multiple similar questions with very manual intensive solutions that are simply not practical in my case:

- [Removing border of symbol in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32404)
- [Forcing QGIS to remove polygon borders?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194277)
- [QGIS renders outlines where none should be](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112930)

This seems to be an old feature request, am I missing something?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.